# Is there any documentation for developing applications on jailbreak iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I wanted to develop an application for jailbroken iphone so that I can access SMS database.

1. Can anyone tell me where to get good
   stuff to start development for
   jailbroken iPhone?
2. Can I use XCODE
   for development? If yes, how can I
   use XCODE?
3. Do I need any provisioning
   profiles while installing
   application on iPhone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

YES, XCode is used to write code, even for jailbroken Apps

If you're developing for a jailbroken app first you need to to set Code Signing Identity to Don't Code Sign, then Build the app but dont Build and Go.

When its done building, SSH into your iPhone and copy your app into /Applications.

Then you need to install Link Identity Editor and Mobile Terminal from Cydia. After it's done installing them, open Mobile Terminal and enter:

Code:

ldid -S /Applications/YourApp.app/YourApp

Then just respring your device with BossPrefs or SBSettings (killall SpringBoard wont work if you are on 2.1+) and your app should appear and your Home Screen

For More Info, have a look at this [Developing for jailbroken iPhone](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=10)

Comment: Does it mean after jailbreaking my iPhone, I can use it like a small Mac machine. Does the procedure remains same as that of Mac application development?

Comment: @Tanu: I am not sure, but I guess it would be same for Mac development too. But for Mac development, there would be other Cydia store. Check this :http://blog.wareseeker.com/fp/technology-news-events/cydia-like-app-store-for-mac-coming-soon/

Comment: Do you know any links for start up tutorials about iPhone open application development (i.e. jailbreak iPhone development)?

Comment: @Tanu: The development process is almost same, infact you can access some more data from iPhone, using undocumented APIs. You need deep knowledge of iOS, so you can traverse/modify the it accordingly. I dont know any book, but there are alot of Open source repositories are available. Have a look at: http://ipodtouchtricks.net/ipod-touch-tricks/list-of-cydia-sources-for-jailbroken-ipod-touch-and-iphone/